# Is this Papaver rhoeas or some other papaver?

Tags: identification

I have an invasion of this plant in my garden this year:

Is this Papaver rhoeas or some other papaver?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: To me it is Papaver rhoeas.  You did a lot of photos, but you miss one important: photo of the capsule. This is one important character of poppies. We see it partially in 3, for this reason I think it is P. rhoeas, but I cannot really see the form. BTW where did you find them?

Comment: @Giacomo I didnt find them, they found me. :) Last yeas I had a piece or two, but this year much more - all in areas that I am intentionally not mowing. Capsules are at this stage rare, and I think this is they way it should be, but I am going to make additional photos.